# gmaps4rails methods - Gmaps.map.centerMapOnUser() and Gmaps.map.markers.length

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

Two questions here, but they're related.  Is there a way to make the `centerMapOnUser()` action smooth?  I have a marker that denotes my location, and it's draggable.

```
// watch for marker movement, and update location accordingly
function updateUserLocation(latLng) {
  var revGeo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  revGeo.geocode({'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        $('#loc').html(results[1].formatted_address); 
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
  });
  Gmaps.map.userLocation = latLng;
  Gmaps.map.centerMapOnUser();
  lat = latLng.lat();
  lng = latLng.lng();
}
```

This is very abrupt, and almost disorienting, though.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to make it a smooth transition.

Side question.  Sometimes the map shows 1 marker, sometimes it shows 26 (A-Z).  If it's only 1, the zoom level is set to max.  I disabled `auto_zoom` and added this function:

```
function zoom() {
  if (Gmaps.map.markers.length == 1) {
    //only one marker, choose the zoom level you expect
    Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(16);
  }
  else{
    //more than one marker, let's auto_zoom
    Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = true;
    Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
  }
}
```

Checking the console, `Gmaps.map.markers` **always** returns 0, whether there are 0, 1, or several markers.  Markers get added initially, though, and even added later on through the `replaceMarkers()` function, so everything *seems* to be configured proper.

Comment: changed the default behavior of the `centerMapOnUser()` function in gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee from `@serviceObject.setCenter(@userLocation)` to `@serviceObject.panTo(@userLocation)` for the first question.  The other is still eluding me.